# MFC CListCtrl drag file to Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, explorer

I am writing an MFC application.

I want to drag file from a `CListCtrl` in my application to Windows Explorer.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to hook up `LVN_BEGINDRAG` to detect the beginning of a drag drop and then call `DoDragDrop` with an `IDataObject` based data source populated with the file information (easiest format to handle is `CF_HDROP`). The Windows shell handles everything else.

Fortunately much of the leg work has already been done for you in the MFC class `COleDataSource`. There are also some great examples available:

[Code Project - How to Implement Drag and Drop Between Your Program and Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840/How-to-Implement-Drag-and-Drop-Between-Your-Progra)

[MSDN - Transferring Shell Objects with Drag-and-Drop and the Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb776905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `OnDrop()` in your `CListCtrl` derived class and provide a `COleDataSource`.